# Custom 404 NUXT3 page not showing up when deploying to Netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, netlify, nuxtjs3

***I'm trying to implement a custom 404 page for my NUXT3 website that is deployed via NETLIFY.***

I created "error.vue" inside the root folder and it's redirecting all errors to my custom 404 page, which is my desired behavior, but when I deploy the site to Netlify on the web it displays a page not found NETLIFY error.

***Anyone that has already implemented a custom 404 Nuxt3 page for a website can help me with this?***

Thanks in advance.

Netlify when 404 error:

[image: Netlify when 404 error:]

Dev 404 error (desired behaviour):

[image: Dev 404 error]

Comment: Does it work if you generate and preview the app locally?

Answer (score 1):

1. put a file named `error.vue` in the root directory of your nuxt project (beside `~/app.vue`). Fill this file just like any component.

If problem still persists:

1. Use `<NuxtErrorBoundary>` as [it's defined in the documentation.](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/components/nuxt-error-boundary#slots)
2. For the netlify case, Add the following to the nuxt.config.js:
   `Generate: { fallback: true }` before building.

Comment: Here is the corresponding part about `~/error.vue` in the Nuxt 3 documentation:
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#rendering-an-error-page

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I added this (see below) to my Nuxt config, as Netlify expects a `404.html` file to show a custom error page. This change correctly redirects to the error page when trying to access a page that doesn't exist, but the status code the error page receives is 500 and not 404.

```
nitro: {
   prerender: {
     routes: ['/404.html']
   }
}
```